# How do i start telnet for hosting terminal games on a mac os x 10.6 Snow leopard

Tags: ruby, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, telnet

How do i start telnet for hosting terminal games on a mac os x 10.6 Snow leopard. My aim is to host terminal applications like games (terminal based) on specific port of my system connected through a static IP.These games are ruby based.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own server, you wouldn't "start a telnet daemon", you'd open the port in your code.

Comment: I am thinking of a simple ruby text based game to host it on telnet, i just cant figure out how to start that in Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.6

Comment: @pankajdoharey It's not an issue of the OS (other than if you want to open a port < 1024), it's a matter of opening ports up *in your code*. Ruby already implements [GServer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/gserver/rdoc/GServer.html) (and [here](http://www.aimred.com/news/developers/2010/01/16/rediscovering_ruby_gserver/)) to get you started.